# After pushing on lambda FCM does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, aws-lambda, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send push notifications in my lambda function. It working as expected on localhost but when I push it to lambda code does not working.
Here is my code:

```
const FCM = require('fcm-node');

let sendNotification = function(regToken) {

let serverKey = 'MY_SERVER_KEY'; 
let fcm = new FCM(serverKey);

let message = { 
    to: regToken,
    notification: {
        title: 'Title of push notification', 
        body: 'Body of push notification' 
    }  
};

fcm.send(message, function(err, response){
    if (err) {
        console.log("Something has gone wrong!", err);
    } else {
        console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Were you able to fix the issue?

Answer (score -1):

You need to encapsulate functions in the exports.handler